# Unable to load gettext module in PHP process

Tags: php, configuration, gettext

The other questions regarding this issue did not solve my problem.

Whenever I try to use the [gettext](https://www.php.net/manual/de/book.gettext.php) module of PHP, I get:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gettext' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829/gettext ... (not found))`.

This to me indicates that the `gettext` module is not present on my mac, or wrongly configured in my `php.ini` file.

I thus ran `php -m` and the output actually lists the `gettext` module, meaning it is installed. I also get that gettext is already installed if I run `brew install gettext`.

A note, I've installed xdebug with their [installation wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard), and I'm unsure if that somehow modified the extensions directory. The reason I think about this possibility is that my `extension_dir` in my `php.ini` file is set to:

`extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20220829"`

Within that directory, there is a single file, a `xdebug.so` file. The [PHPDocs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/gettext.installation.php) then mention that the default gettext installation location is `/usr/local`. My PHPinfo output however says `'--with-gettext=/usr/local/opt/gettext'` within the `Configure Command` options, so I feel that the actual location of my gettext location is in there. In that `/usr/local/opt/gettext` directory, I can indeed find a lot of files related to gettext.

As weird as it can be:

`var_dump(extension_loaded('gettext'));`

ouputs:

`bool(true)`

but only if I comment out

`;extension=gettext`

in my `php.ini` file.

The warning mentioned at the very beginning of my question also only shows up if I enable the line:

`extension=gettext`

My question now is: How can make my gettext extension, which is already installed, work, while keeping the xdebug extension working, in light of the above?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved; the issues was that I was completely unaware that, for PHP gettext to work, you have to respect the folder logic :

`/your-translations-directory/locale/LC_MESSAGES/domain_name.mo`

e.g., to get the translations in german (germany) of a string of the 'random' text domain, you would need to do:

`/your-translations-directory/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/random.mo`

When doing so, it wasn't even necessary to uncomment the line

`extension=gettext`

in my `php.ini` file, it all worked either way as soon as I respected the above-mentioned folder structure.